# Entity Framework 6 not compatible with Data Annotations from system.componentmodel.annotations(net standard compatible) assembly?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, data-annotations, .net-standard-2.0, system.componentmodel

I'm trying to use Entity Framework with a set of entities defined as a part of net standard2.0 nuget package. The project that uses Entity framework is a net472 project. When I'm building the model in tests, I'm seeing the below error

```
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

CodeFirstNamespace.<TestEntity>: : EntityType 'TestEntity' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
TestEntities: EntityType: EntitySet 'TestEntity' is based on type 'TestEntity' that has no keys defined.
```

The above error says that one of the entities does not have keys defined, but it has key attributed defined. Below is the entity definition

```
[Table("TestEntity")]
[FilterSupported]
internal sealed class TestEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Column("entity1Id", Order = 1)]
    public int TestId{ get; set; }

    public RelatedEntity entity1Id{ get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("entity2", Order = 2)]
    public int entity2Id { get; set; }

    public RelatedEntity2 entity2 { get; set; }
}
```

Below are the references used in the project

- Entity Framework 6
- System.ComponentModel.Annotations 4.7  (for net standard compatibility needed for our entities nuget)
- entities dll (net standard 2.0 nuget)

This definition worked fine till "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" was replaced with "System.ComponentModel.Annotations".

Is there any way that I can fix this or should I move to use Entity core as it supports dot net standard ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the .NET 4.7.2 project, remove the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations reference and instead, reference the same Nuget package (System.ComponentModel.Annotations).  You will probably have to add a binding redirect.

Comment: This was a solution to my problem. Thanks